# How to save raw HTTP POST data using ajax and Python CGI

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cgi

Is it even possible? Im trying to do something like this

```
function sendToServer(){
var jsonObj = {ip: ip, port: port, stime: stime, maxsamples: maxsamples, dplaces: dplaces};
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonStr);
console.log(jsonObj);


$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
data: jsonStr,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response){
    console.log(response)
    },
    error: function (xhr,status,error){
        alert(error.message);
        alert(error.response);
    }

 });
};
```

I have no problem with retrieving the data in Python file. I can even modify it and get modified response. But if i try to save what i send I get an error saying "undefined". Both browsers Firefox and Chromium are saying that's error 500.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi, cgitb
import json
import sys
import os


content_len = int(os.environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"])
req_body = sys.stdin.read()
myjson = json.loads(req_body)

# data modification
myjson["ip"] = "do sth"

print('Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n')
#  2 troublesome lines
open with("config.json", "w") as file:
    file.write(myjson)




print(json.dumps(myjson))
```

I don't know what am I missing. I guess with flask it would be easier but I need to try it like this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Some questions to help: Is data written to `config.json` ? Are you using a relative path when you should be using an absolute path? Do you have permission to write to the file? Should you convert `myjson` back to a string using `json.loads(myjson)`

Comment: @JacobIRR If I put some mock json string instead of reading it from stdin and run script standalone it  works well. I mean it writes data to file with no problem

Answer (score 0):

It came out that the owner and group of the folder where files were, was wrong. Server should be the owner. So scripts are correct they work properly everything I had to do was type [chown](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chown.1.html) in console:/